# Detect support for live streaming formats in HTML 5

Tags: html, video, http-live-streaming

There's lots of guidance on detecting browser support for the video tag, and using the codecs to specify alternative media types based on codec support. Or using players like JWPlayer to do this for you.

But I'm doing live streaming. So I need to sniff for more than just video/H.264 support - I want to detect whether HTTP live streaming (or some of the alternatives) are supported too.

(eg: Chrome Mobile on Android 4.1: Supports the Video tag, but HLS/H.264 isn't supported in-browser, but if I redirect to the manifest directly, it opens in the video player app, and plays just fine)

Is this possible? I really want to avoid resorting to version sniffing. At worst I'd accept being able to sniff (somehow) that the video tag failed to load.